# Lotus notes 8.5 enable clickable hyperlink in edit mode

Tags: lotus-notes

I would like to get a clickable link in an edit mode of the Lotus Notes 8.5. Now I am only able to see the link if I go to the options or if I send the email to myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can CTRL+Click the link, not sure if this was added in 8.5 or 9.0

Comment: Not a solution but you can do CTRL+E to get from Edit Mode to Read mode

Comment: Thomas, thanks for the answer. To be more clear I press "New email" button in Notes and I want to have the "Read" mode there. However, the CTRL+E does not work in this instance. (it does work if I open an email I have received and switch the modes there)

Comment: I am using v9 and I can CTRL+Click or Right-click a link and choose "Open Hotspot".

Comment: is it correct that I can use the CTRL+E only once? If I open a new Stationery or a draft email I am able to go to read and edit mode once, but afterwards I am not able to do it. If I press CTRL+E I am taken to the window as if I have pressed x button (namely I am offered to send, save as draft, etc.)

Comment: Ask your IT department why you are using a 5 year old version of Notes

Comment: That will not help :) and the Notes are 8.5.3 FP5, so almost 2 year old, but in any case quite old.